# Building Poco libraries with legacy MacOs SDK

Tags: macos, poco-libraries

I updated Xcode and it also updated MacOS SDK. I need to build Poco with older SDK to support older MacOS versions. I want to build with MacOS version 10.11. I've downloaded the legacy MacOs SDK and want to give the path to it with some kind of a flag.

My build command looks as follows:

```
./configure --omit=Data/ODBC,Data/MySQL,Zip,JSON,MongoDB,PageCompiler,PageCompiler/File2Page,CppUnit --no-tests --no-samples --cflags=-fPIC --sqlite-thread-safe=1 --include-path=$(pwd)/$(openssldir)/$(opensslincdirname) --library-path=$(pwd)/$(openssldir) && \
make clean && \
make
```

I already tried adding flags With:

```
CFLAGS="-isysroot ~/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.11
```

To check if the built library is built with correct SDK I used the `otool` command: (this is what it should look like)

```
otool -l filename.dylib

 cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX
 cmdsize 16
 version 10.8
 sdk 10.11
```

For xcodeproject this worked:

```
xcodebuild -sdk macosx10.11 -project projectname.xcodeproj
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing multiple different flags I came to a solution that worked as expected.

Here is the same make command with proper MACOS SDK reference:

```
./configure --omit=Data/ODBC,Data/MySQL,Zip,JSON,MongoDB,PageCompiler,PageCompiler/File2Page,CppUnit --no-tests --no-samples --cflags=-fPIC --sqlite-thread-safe=1 --include-path=$(pwd)/$(openssldir)/$(opensslincdirname) --library-path=$(pwd)/$(openssldir) && \
make clean && \
make MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8 MACOSX_SDK_VERSION_MIN=10.9 SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk
```

I downloaded legacy MacOS SDK from https://github.com/devernay/xcodelegacy and put it into the Xcode SDK folder. It's worth to note that this folder might be cleared when updating XCode so it might make sense to use a symlink to the sdk directory and keep the legacy SDK elsewhere.